# api версионирование

Tags: api

есть бэкенд приложение api, пути вида

```
api.site.com/v1/users
```

По этому пути может подключиться клиент, имеющий токен и права на просмотр пользователей, и SPA приложение, в котором сидит пользователь без токена, но с нужными разрешениями.

Смущает версионирование. Зачем оно мне нужно для SPA? То есть, если произойдет серьезное изменение по пути, мне руками нужно будет поменять везде v1 на v2 где используется запрос по такому пути? Я что-то упускаю? Как это реализовывается обычно?

Answer (score 0):

Версионирование для того и нужно, чтобы делать новые фичи в v2 и не ломать логику в v1.

API должен жить максимально долго, пока не устанешь поддерживать старые версии

Comment: а зачем оно для spa? ведь по факту версия 2 и будет делаться под spa, не лучше ли иметь /users вместо /v1/users для спа? а для внешних оставить версионирование? или например spa/users ?

Comment: Возможно, я что такое SPA не оч в курсе)

Comment: single page application, сайт грубо говоря

Comment: А вам точно нужно API? Может быть вас интересует wsgi какой-нибудь. API штука большая, требующая долгой поддержки, она все время обновляется, клиенты под нее обновляться не очень спешат